# nodejs - how to get the directory size recursively?

Tags: javascript, node.js

how to get the folder size recursively using only native javascript and output it in this form:

```
dir1 (1000kb)<br>
— subDir1 (500kb)<br>
——— subFile1 (300kb)<br>
——— subFile2 (200kb)<br>
— subDir2 (500)<br>
——— subFile1 (500kb)<br>
```

my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');


function scaner(y,counter = ''){
    counter += '-';
    let y1 = fs.readdirSync(y);
    for(let x of y1){
        console.log(`${counter}` + x);
        let stat = fs.statSync(y + x);
        if(!stat.isFile()){
            let path = y + x + '/';
            scaner(path,counter);
        }
    }
}
scaner('./');
```

Comment: Whats the exact problem?

Comment: Does this need to work on all platforms? Or Unix-based is fine?

Comment: @jonas-w 
the problem is that you need to calculate the size of the folder recursively and output it. The code will output only the name of the folders and files, you need to add the size of the folders.